# Limit function of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^{k+1}x^k\over k!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I need to compute the limit function of:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^{k+1}x^k\over k!}$$

I know that the series is convergent (because it´s absolutely convergent) but I have no idea how to compute the limit function

Any hints, ideas or suggestions would be highly appreaciated

Comment: How much do you know about the exponential function?

Comment: I know that it´s taylor series is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{x^k\over k!}$ but I haven´t been able to give an expression that involves $e^x$ in the first series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may recall that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}=e^z,\qquad \quad z \in \mathbb{C},
$$ then put $z:=-x$ and observe that $z^k=(-1)^k x^k$.